# Opening SAP Logon Pad with VBA for any windows user profile

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Unload LOGINZGLOC

Dim strPath As String

strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\saplgpad.lnk"

Shell "strPath", 4

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do Until WshShell.AppActivate("SAP Logon Pad")
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
Loop

Dim Row
Dim UD As Worksheet
Set UD = Application.ActiveSheet

Row = 3

Set SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set Appl = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = Appl.Openconnection("[GT] ECC Production (GE4)", True)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)
```

This is the code I use for opening SAP using login info got from a userform. But since this is a code that's meant to be used by several employees and working colleagues, I need to open SAP on any user profile, for that I tried creating a shortcut and referencing to him on Desktop, since I'm new to VBA the code might look a little raw. The code fails, saying that the file couldn't be found.

Comment: _The code fails, saying that the file couldn't be found._ <= At which line do you get this error?

Comment: strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\saplgpad.lnk"
This line